# Fractional share left after a reverse split

Tags: stock-split, fractional-shares

I have a short position.  It reverse split and now I’m left with a fractional share.

How do I buy to cover on E*Trade when it won’t accept the .5 share along with the others? Why wouldn’t they round up or down?

Comment: The fractional share might get auto-treated once you handle the full shares. Two of my brokers claim they do it so. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional shares due to a reverse split are handled a number of ways and it depends on the company and the broker.

If your broker offers the ability to trade fractional shares then there's no problem.

Some brokers will sell your soon to be fractional shares before the split.

If you have fractional shares after a reverse split, for the fractional shares you may receive:

- A cash-in-lieu payment
- Additional shares  rounding up to a whole number
- Nothing

In your case, you should call E*Trade and ask them what the solution is.